# How to export projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an eclipse workspace with 2 non-web based projects, with over a dozen jars as maven dependencies.  How do I transfer this to run on another computer that does not have eclipse?   Do I export as a war, jar, or wnat?

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to export this as an eclipse project, or include a pom. I just want to export the jars and files needed to run the application from the command line.  It is not web based, and does not run in a container like tomcat.

Comment: I would suggest, build the respective projects with maven as you have maven projects, copy the war or jar files to another computer.

Comment: How do I copy the jars?  They are spread out in various location under the m2 folder. If I try to copy from eclipse, it doesnt seem to work.  I thought I could export the required supporting files into a container file like a jar, war, or ear file?

Comment: Sir, Could you please check the answer, hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question about copying the projects to another computer, I provide below the followings.

1. Build the maven project, if it is a web application, copy the .war file which contains all the dependent libraries inside web-inf/lib.
2. Build the maven project, if it is a non-web application, copy the jar file only. To copy all the dependent jar files, you need to identify. Follow the step 3..
3. To copy or identify the all the dependent jar files for a project, there is no need to go to .m2 directory and search. Go the project directory and run the maven command `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`. You will find all the dependent jar files inside the target folder. If you want, you can copy all the jar files.
4. If the project is a maven based project, you can directly copy the entire project to another computer and if maven setup is there in that computer, you can still build the project there. You do not need eclipse in that computer.
5. I would suggest if a project has maven wrapper, while copying the entire project, there is no need to install maven. In that case, go to command prompt for that project and type `mvnw clean install` or `mvnw clean package`.
6. If you want to copy or export the project using eclipse, you can do it like this. Make right click on the project, select export and then select General > Archive File.